# How can I program an application on the for the .net framework 1.0?

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

I have a Windows 7 machine and I see that Microsoft does not recommend Visual Studio 2003 on the computer (Windows 7). How can I develop an application for the .net framework 1.0 then? I currently have visual basic express 2010.

EDIT: 1.0 runs on older machines that require administrator to update.

Comment: Why in the world would you want to do that? 2.0 is still solid and widely used and that's as far back as I would go...

Comment: May I ask why you'd want to target the 1.0 Framework, versus 4.0 or even 3.5?

Comment: How could I get Visual basic 2003 anyway?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only OS that 1.0 [supports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) that 2.0 doesn't is windows millennium  (windows 98 is supported on both) so why you would need to target 1.0 at all? Windows 98/Me fall into the [less than 0.5% of users territory](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_os.asp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VS 2010 will only let you target back to 2.0 Framework.  You can either put XP on your development machine, or use a virtual machine with XP to put VS 2003 on it.

Comment: XP in virtual machine feels much better than installing 1.X framework on Win7.

Comment: You don't need to install VS to develop (or build) software for a particular .NET version.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a way to do it. It does not seem to be supported but you can give this a try.
[Installing 1.X Framework on Win7](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/how-to-install-net-framework-11-in-windows-7-64/eb1e6232-e874-432e-ab43-17660e25e43d)

Comment: Yes, but are you going to trust anything that comes from that?

Comment: try that before or after shooting self in the foot?